# Getting error when trying to store loop to array

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm getting this error every time I try to save the data..[image]

But when i use dd() the array is working fine[image]

**Details**

**Model:**Parents[Term & Level] **Junction:**:***(Model:term_level, Table: term_levels)***

**TermModel:**

```
 public function level(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Level::class, 'term_levels','Term_id', 'Level_id');
  }
```

**LevelModel:**

```
public function term(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Term::class, 'term_levels', 'Level_id', 'Term_id');
  }
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function store_term_level(Request $request)

{
    $data=$request->all();

    foreach($data['Term_id'] as $termId){
        $term = Term::find($termId);
        $levelids = $data['Level_id'];
        $term->level()->attach($levelids);
        $term_level=new term_level;
        $term_level->Term_id=$request->input('Term_id');
        $term_level->Level_id=$request->input('Level_id');

        $term_level->save();

}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of `dd($data);` before the foreach loop?

Comment: why are you trying to store in `$term_level` separately. `$term->level()->attach($levelids);` this code will store your level_id and term_id in `term_levels`

Comment: bro i fix already  all i did i add jason encode on the last part it works well jason turn it into array..hehe

Comment: yes that's exactly the plan to store termid and levelid to term_level table which is the many to many approach cos term can have levels vice versa..

Comment: one of your array items is a string, first check is array then store it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the correct answer i convert it into jason_array

```
 $data=$request->all();
    foreach($data['Term_id'] as $term){
        $term = Term::find($term);
        $level = $data['Level_id'];
        $term->level()->attach($level);
        $term_level=new term_level;
        $term_level->Term_id=$request->input('Term_id');
        $term_level->Level_id=$request->input('Level_id');
       //this code solve the problem..
        $term_level = json_encode($data, true);

}
```

Comment: But `json_encode($data, true);` is not responsible fir saving data. For Saving data in your code responsible only this code `$term->level()->attach($level)`; . Last 4 lines not need  delete it and try again.  ask me about result

Comment: jason is one who convert it into a proper array cos im getting the data through loop  so jason help me u can try  and see what will happen..

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
public function store_term_level(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    foreach ($data['Term_id'] as $termId) {
        foreach ($data['Level_id'] as $levelId) {
            $term_level = new term_level;
            $term_level->Term_id = $termId;
            $term_level->Level_id = $levelId;
            $term_level->save();
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
$terms = Term::whereIn('id', $data['Term_id'])->get();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $levelids = $data['Level_id'];
    $term->level()->attach($levelids);
}
```

Comment: the first code works perfect thanks you.. i cannot check it cos already have answer but your'e code work.. thank you so much..

Comment: Two soluntions must be perfectly work. But second solution is more perfect solution then first solution because it is more time smaller request done in database then first solution

Comment: about the second answer, what if u have add more items like grade_id Section_id is it possible? in the first answer yes i have added two more which is section_id and Grade_id

Comment: the second answer is targeting the term_id it reference through the term_id. where the first answer is targeting all the request and break it down to single then loop it..

Answer (score 1):

```
$terms = Term::whereIn('id', $data['Term_id'])->get();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $levelids = $data['Level_id'];
    $term->level()->attach($levelids);
}
```

It is better solution, because it is doing smaller request to DB